# MicrosoftSQL: How to create a table inside a Trigger and insert values

Tags: sql-server, triggers

im trying to create a trigger on a table with the follow characteristics

1. Whenever and UPDATE is used on Project_Ypalliloi (table name) i would like to **Create** another Table (for instance deleted_Ypalliloi)
2. I would like to take the deleted line, and insert it into the new Table

this is my table:

```
create table Project_Ypalliloi
(
arithmos_taut int primary key not null,
onoma varchar(20)not null,
eponymo varchar(20)not null,
imerominia_proslipsis date not null,
imerominia_gennisis date not null,
misthos float

)
```

this is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleteTrigger ON Project_Ypalliloi FOR DELETE AS --errorline1
DECLARE @arithmos_taut int
DECLARE @onoma varchar(20)
DECLARE @eponymo varchar(20)
DECLARE @imerominia_proslipsis date
DECLARE @imerominia_gennisis date
DECLARE @misthos float
DECLARE @getnamesCursor CURSOR 
SET @getnamesCursor = CURSOR FOR 
SELECT arithmos_taut,onoma,eponymo,imerominia_proslipsis,imerominia_gennisis,misthos FROM Project_Ypalliloi --where How can i get the deleted line?(under what condition?)
OPEN @getnamesCursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM @getnamesCursor INTO @arithmos_taut,@onoma,@eponymo,@imerominia_proslipsis,@imerominia_gennisis,@misthos 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO deleted_Ypalliloi Values '('+rtrim(@arithmos_taut) + ',' + rtrim(@onoma) + ',' + rtrim(@eponymo) + ' ,' + rtrim(@imerominia_proslipsis) + ',' + rtrim(@imerominia_gennisis) + ', ' + rtrim(@misthos)+')' 
--FETCH NEXT FROM @getnamesCursor INTO @c_name,@c_surname 
END --errorline 2
CLOSE @getnamesCursor 
DEALLOCATE @getnamesCursor
```

> My trigger code is in the Query,and i get an error:"Incorrect Syndax at **`errorline 1`** and **`errorline 2`**

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

USE "FROM DELETED"

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleteTrigger ON Project_Ypalliloi AFTER DELETE 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @arithmos_taut int;
DECLARE @onoma varchar(20);
DECLARE @eponymo varchar(20);
DECLARE @imerominia_proslipsis date;
DECLARE @imerominia_gennisis date;
DECLARE @misthos float;
SELECT @arithmos_taut = arithmos_taut, 
@onoma = onoma, @eponymo = eponymo, 
@imerominia_proslipsis = imerominia_proslipsis,
@imerominia_gennisis = imerominia_gennisis, 
@misthos = misthos FROM DELETED;
INSERT INTO deleted_Ypalliloi 
VALUES(@arithmos_taut, @onoma, @eponymo, @imerominia_proslipsis, @imerominia_gennisis, @misthos);
END
```

For two or more deleted rows

```
INSERT INTO deleted_Ypalliloi SELECT * FROM DELETED;
```

Comment: That will not work if there is more than 1 row in `DELETED` table.

Comment: maybe i can try to check somehow if there is more than 1 row.You think that would work?

Comment: Do i have to create first a table that is called deleted_Ypalliloi?

Comment: It actually not work if i have only 1 row in the table Project_Ypalliloi

Comment: Also , what is the DELETED table? `@misthos = misthos FROM DELETED;`

Comment: "DELETED" is not a table is a reference for the "deleted data" (1 or more rows) but my example only works if 1 row is deleted if more rows are deleted you can try: INSERT INTO deleted_Ypalliloi SELECT * FROM DELETED;